# Going through all binary combinations with some numbers as "?"

Tags: python, recursion, binary

I have to generate all the possible binary representations of a given string, where some characters are "?" and others are 1 or 0.

I'm trying to do a recursive search but I encounter some weird problems I can't figure out.

```
userInput = list(input())
anslist = []
def fill(inp):
    #print(inp)
    if inp.count("?") == 0:
        print(inp, "WAS ADDED")
        anslist.append(inp)
        return


    for a in range(0, len(userInput)):
        if inp[a] == "?":
            inp[a] = 1
            fill(inp)
            inp[a] = 0
            fill(inp)
            return
print(anslist)
```

For the input ?01?1 I should be getting:
00101, 00111, 10101 and 10111
but I get 
10111
10101
00101 printed out. In addition, anslist isn't working properly. I just can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: use python [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to generate all combinations of 1 and 0 for all ? positions and one by one assign to an array and push to anslist

Comment: if you dont want to use itertools.product you can use nested loops (for fixed number of positions)or more generaly recursion

Comment: I don't want to use builtin tools. Also, I can't know the amount of elements (=amount of loops) so recursion is the way to go.

Comment: @PatrickArtner nope, I'm here to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) is a *mutable* type, that means that you only have **one** list on which all modifications are made. This causes your first call `fill(inp)` to also fill the remaining '?' in `inp`, thus only giving you one result with the second option for the first ? (first ?=1: two results, first ?=0: one result because the last result of the first ? is still saved in the list)

To resolve this problem, use `list.copy()`. This will pass a copy of the list to `fill()` and thus cause the original list to be left as it is.

Your complete code with `.copy()` and other minor modifications:

```
anslist = []
def fill(inp):
    if inp.count("?") == 0:
        print(inp, "WAS ADDED")
        anslist.append(inp)
        return

    for a in range(len(inp)):  # range(0, x) is equivalent to range(x); try to limit global variables
        if inp[a] == "?":
            inp[a] = 1
            fill(inp.copy())  # list is mutable
            inp[a] = 0
            fill(inp.copy())  # see above
            return
user_input = list(input())
fill(user_input)
print(anslist)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's example solution without using builtin tools. Here we use recursion, when we occur '?' during iterating over our input we replace it with '0' and '1' and add result of `fill()` of what's after current index.

```
userInput = input()

def fill(inp):
    ret = []
    for idx, i in enumerate(inp):
        if i == '?':
            for rest in fill(inp[idx+1:]):
                ret.append(inp[:idx] + '0' + rest)
                ret.append(inp[:idx] + '1' + rest)
            break
    else:
        return [inp]
    return ret

print(fill(userInput))
```

**Output**

```
?01?1 -> ['00101', '10101', '00111', '10111']
???   -> ['000', '100', '010', '110', '001', '101', '011', '111']
```

Comment: this is quite nice :)

Comment: Seeing how good your answer is I wanted to delete mine :D but I'm glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools
import re

inp = "?01?1"
for combination in itertools.product("01", repeat=inp.count("?")):
    i_combination = iter(combination)
    print(re.sub("\?",lambda m: next(i_combination),inp))
```

this just uses the builtin `itertools.product` to create all possible strings of "01" of length N(however many question-marks there are in the string)

then it converts each one of those into an iterator where each item is consumed as soon as it is seen,

then we use `re.sub` to substitute our products into our original strings, in place of our question-marks

here it is in a repl https://repl.it/@JoranBeasley/AssuredAncientOpengroup

I see in a comment here you dont want to use builtins ... so nevermind then i guess

if you do not want to use builtin itertools.product .. .simply write your own

```
def my_product(s,r):
  if r < 1:
    yield ""
  for i in range(r):
    for c in s:
      for partial in  my_product(s,r-1):
        yield c+partial
```

same with built in iter

```
def my_iter(s):
    for c in s:
        yield c
```

and lastly we need to write our own custom subber

```
def my_substitute(s,replacement):
    iter_replacement = my_iter(replacement)
    while s.count("?"):
         s = s.replace("?",next(iter_replacement))
    return s
```

now we tie it all together in the same way

```
inp = "?01?1"
for combination in my_product("01", inp.count("?")):
    print(my_substitute(inp,combination))
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution that avoids using a global or a library:

```
def fill(digits):

    if not digits:
        return []

    first, *rest = digits

    strings = fill(rest) if rest else ['']

    if first == '?':
        return ['0' + string for string in strings] + ['1' + string for string in strings]

    return [first + string for string in strings]

userInput = input()

print(fill(userInput))
```

Tries to *spell things out* rather than make the most efficient array operations, which is left as an exercise for the OP.

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
?01?1
['00101', '00111', '10101', '10111']
> python3 test.py
???
['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
> python3 test.py
?
['0', '1']
> python3 test.py

[]
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample python code using [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) (you can use an equivalent implementation but this is fine)

```
from itertools import product

def generate_combinations(inp):
   count = 0 
   for a in range(0, len(inp)):
      if inp[a] == "?": count += 1
   combinations = []
   for comb in product(range(2), repeat=count):
      pos = 0
      cinp = inp[:]
      for a in range(len(cinp)):
         if cinp[a] == '?':
           cinp[a] = str(comb[pos])
           pos += 1
       combinations.append(cinp)
    return combinations
```

example usage:

```
print(generate_combinations('?01?1'))
```