# Wordlist generator: Permutation inside permutation

Tags: python, permutation

I am trying to code a wordlist generator. So far I succeed to have permutations of base words and numbers.

The problem I need help for it is, I want to insert number permutations into word permutations. (There is placeholder chars ("+") in permutated words' strings.) Also I can insert string into a string and know the placeholders' indexes. The problem is not including them.

For example (succeed part):

```
permutatedwords = ["+me+you+", "+you+me+"]`
permutatednums = ["1", "2", "12", "21"]
```

Needed output is (asking for help part):

```
outList = ["1you1me1", "1you1me2", "1you2me1", "1you2me2", "2you1me1", "2you1me2", "2you2me1", "2you2me2"]
```

Well, obviously, I need a function for this.

(I know that the title is not fit well for the content, so feel free to modify it. When modified, you can delete this sentence.)

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. What have you tried so far to solve the problem? You might try checking out this help page for information on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: __[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54065561/going-through-all-binary-combinations-with-some-numbers-as)__  are some solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use itertools' combinations_with_replacement to generate the number part of the merge.  Then replace the pluses with each number in each combination:

```
permutatedwords = ["+me+you+", "+you+me+"]
permutatednums = ["1", "2", "12", "21"]

from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as combinationsR

wordsAndNums = [ (word,numbers) for word in permutatedwords for numbers in combinationsR(permutatednums,word.count("+")) ]
result = [ "".join(a+b for a,b in zip(word.split("+")+[""],nums)) for word,nums in wordsAndNums]

print(result)
['1me1you1', '1me1you2', '1me1you12', '1me1you21', '1me2you2', 
 '1me2you12', '1me2you21', '1me12you12', '1me12you21', '1me21you21',
 '2me2you2', '2me2you12', '2me2you21', '2me12you12', '2me12you21', 
 '2me21you21', '12me12you12', '12me12you21', '12me21you21', '21me21you21',
 '1you1me1', '1you1me2', '1you1me12', '1you1me21', '1you2me2', '1you2me12',
 '1you2me21', '1you12me12', '1you12me21', '1you21me21', '2you2me2', 
 '2you2me12', '2you2me21', '2you12me12', '2you12me21', '2you21me21', 
 '12you12me12', '12you12me21', '12you21me21', '21you21me21']
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you. It worked and I am reverse engineering it to actually fit my program. Also I am marking this as an valid answer.