# Making a list with python and in the list a character should be replaced with a random number

Tags: python

Can someone show me how to replace a character with random numbers, I mean

```
ZYGu*5ed2jvQVWsf1w*A
```

The `*` to be replaced with random numbers, at the output to be **all the possibilities of combination**

> ZYGu`0`5ed2jvQVWsf1w`0`A
>
> ZYGu`0`5ed2jvQVWsf1w`1`A
>
> ZYGu`0`5ed2jvQVWsf1w`2`A
>
> ...
>
> ZYGu`9`5ed2jvQVWsf1w`9`A

All the way until the numbers are replaced with 9 and 9. I have no idea how to do it, some ideas please?

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I tried x = random.randrange(0,10) y = random.randrange(0,10) print("ZYGu" ,x, "5ed2jvQVWsf1w" ,y, "A")..but its printing only once and with spaces between the string and the random numbers...i want to print all the combinations possible(100)

Comment: [This problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54065561/going-through-all-binary-combinations-with-some-numbers-as) is the same as yours.

Comment: Thanks, I found what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple to solve..  You can observe the below steps and make optimizations as per your need:

1. Split your text

```
import re
arr = re.split('(\*)', "ZYGu*5ed2jvQVWsf1w*A")
```

2. Get the count of all the stars *

```
star_count = arr.count("*")
```

3. Create a list of combination of 2 digits:

```
import itertools
from itertools import product
a = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]
print (list(product(a, repeat=2)))

combinations = list(set(itertools.permutations(a, star_count)))
```

4. Start trying out the combination by replacing appropriate elements of your array and then finally joining it

```
for item in combinations:
    new_arr = arr.copy()
    new_arr[1] = str(item[0])
    new_arr[3] = str(item[1])
    print(''.join(new_arr))
```

Hope this helps!!

> > Note: This is done for demo purposes and there is room for improvement.