# How to make a python script that gives you every iteration of a string from a pattern

Tags: python, arrays, iteration

So I'm trying to make a python script that takes a pattern (ex: *c**l*) where it'll return every iteration of the string (* = any character in the alphabet)...

So, we get something like: *caal*, *cbal*, *ccal* and so forth.
I've tried using the itertools library's product but I haven't been able to make it work properly. So after 2 hours I've decide to turn to Stack Overflow.

Here's my current code. It's not complete since I feel stuck

```
alphabet = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')

wildChar = False
tmp_string = ""
combinations = []

if '*' in pattern:
    wildChar = True
    tmp_string = pattern.replace('*', '', pattern.count('*')+1)

if wildChar:
    tmp = []
    for _ in range(pattern.count('*')):
        tmp.append(list(product(tmp_string, alphabet)))
    
        for array in tmp:
            for instance in array:
                
                combinations.append("".join(instance))
                tmp = []

print(combinations)
```

Comment: So what have you got so far after those two hours? Show us...

Comment: Hint: use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Comment: Like the 2 answers below see [Joran Beasley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54065561/going-through-all-binary-combinations-with-some-numbers-as)'s answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase

pattern = "c**l"
repeat = pattern.count("*")
pattern = pattern.replace("*", "{}")
for letters in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=repeat):
    print(pattern.format(*letters))
```

Result:

```
caal
cabl
cacl
...
czxl
czyl
czzl
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.product`

```
import itertools
import string

s = 'c**l'
l = [c if c != '*' else string.ascii_lowercase) for c in s]
out = [''.join(c) for c in itertools.product(*l)]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
['caal',
 'cabl',
 'cacl',
 'cadl',
 'cael',
 'cafl',
 'cagl',
 'cahl',
 'cail',
 'cajl'
 ...
```